# Optimizing ArcGIS Desktop performance using MXD Defrag?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, performance, mxd

Does the MXD Defrag program still exist in ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 5):

The MXD Defrag program is installed (on my Win 7 machine) here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Tools\DocDefragmenter.exe

Just a couple of things I've changed so far - In the Advanced setting utility:

I set the temporary metafile size limit to 10MB. Not because of anything I've run into in Arc10 yet, but I did have problems in 9.3 and earlier, and this setting seemed to help.

I set the Output raster buffer size to 32MB in order to improve image export speed.

Comment: Have you messed with the length of time it holds the Geoprocessing log? I set it to one day out of habit.

Comment: Under Geoprocessing Options > Results Management > Keep results younger than ... ?

I was actually thinking of increasing it to a month or more. There have been times when I've had to go back and retrieve something.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 1 month is way over of what you need under this matter. More like a week. I doubt that you will be able to remember what output/input gave you the results one month ago.

Comment: George - I have been looking into this some more, and it works differently than I had first thought. It only saves ENTRIES in the results window for the time specified, not the actual data. Also, all of the results in the window are loaded every time you open ArcMap, so too many entries WILL slow things down. +1 to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Using the Document Defragmenter utility](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000300000017000000.htm)  might be helpful:

> The ArcGIS Document Defragmenter utility defragments the storage
>   inside an .mxd file to potentially reduce the file size. This utility
>   is useful if your .mxd files are large in size. The utility can also
>   defragment .sxd, .3dd, and, .mxt files. The utility is located in the
>   Utilities folder of the ArcGIS Desktop installation directory. By
>   default, that location is :\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Tools.